# How to send javascript objects from Html.actionlink() method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code

```
@Html.ActionLink("order","ProceedToPay","Shop",new {/*how to access JS objects here*/ },new {@class="btn btn-primary" })
```

i am calling ProceedToPay action of controller Shop and the data i want to send to the action is let's say:

```
@section Scripts()
{
<script>
 var objectDeclaredInJavascriptIwantToSend={//some data};
</script>
}
```

how do i send this object in actionlink method?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate mistakes:

1. You wanna share server and client side variables while **they don't
   live at the same time**.
2. The `@Html.ActionLink()` method will generate a url link to the
   given Controller Action. Thus, it can only contain *parameters*. **You cannot pass an object through the url unless serializing all the object properties as url parameters and receive them as expected in controller side**

In case of variable sharing, You can do the entire operation with javascript. Create an event (if not use `document.ready`) to place the js parameter(s) inside `href` attribute in html rendered form of razor.